# Does LINQ Select affect on performance?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Let's say I have an object of a list of objects which has 30 properties like this :

```
List<myObject> objectList = db.myObject.Where(x => x.Brand == "Ford").ToList();
```

And objectList has about 250k members.

If I get only two properties from db and make a list like this :

```
List<myObject2> objectList2 = (from x in db.myObject
                                 where x.Brand == "Ford"
                                  select new myObject2 {Brand = x.Brand, userId = x.userId}).ToList();
```

This list also has 250k members but the objects in this list has 2 properties. 
Would traversing in the second list be faster than the first one? Or would it be same? Please enlighten me. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by *faster*. SQL query will be faster (less data to fetch: *all* columns versus *two*) when the final `List<T>` is not.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko when I search for an object in those lists(when they are both in memory) it would be the same, right?

Comment: it is; `foreach (var item in objectList) {...}` and `foreach (var item2 in objectList2) {...}` will be of the same speed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Linq-statements are translated to SQL - something like this

```
select brand, userId from myTable where Brand == "Ford"
```

When you omit the projection within your Linq-statement the following sql is emited instead:

```
select * from myTable where Brand == "Ford"
```

This returns *all* columns from your table. So of course specifiying the returned columns should be faster in this case than just omitting the projection.

EDIT: However the performance of *traversing* from one element within your `ResultSet` to the next won´t shouldn´t have a big impact, the bigger one is the actual size of data to be fetched from the database.

Comment: My question is would it be faster when I traverse in that list... For example would it be faster if I make a search in that list?

Comment: In general, no, the same in-memory search would not be much different. If you want it faster search at the database level (with proper indexing etc.).

Comment: @jason: As with all things performance related go and measure it. Profile your code, see if there actually is a bottleneck here, if there is try to fix it and measure the improvement.